# How can i add coordinates of Polygon nodes on a Polygon data table?

Tags: qgis, table, feature-layer

I'm new in this domain and I want to know if I can add to data table of a Polygon.shp, coordinates of node. I have this table pkuid/ name_poly/ area/ lenght/ (here nr_point ex:1,2,3,4 it' about order/ x or long/ y or lat/ and other things about poly. I need in this format because I want a simple format for daily use by people who doesn't know how to manipulate layers of QGIS. At this moment I have already 2 layers one with points (coordinates) and one with polygons.

Answer (score 2):

Calculating the WKT (Well Known Text) format for each geometry will allow you to put the nodes of your polygon into the table.

Start editing the polygon layer (`View|Toggle editing` or toolbar button), then open the attribute table.

[image]

Create a new field (ctrl-W) called 'geom' (or 'nodes' or whatever) as text, with an appropriate length:

[image]

Calculate the WKT for the geometry for each polygon with `geom_to_wkt($geometry)` (click 'update all' after entering the expression):

[image]